# Order items by n number of dates and fetch the closest to today

Tags: php, sorting, date

I have a website that displays events; Each event can have x number of dates (no limits).
I need to display on the main page the event that is closest to today's date.

This should be a no-brainer, but it's not working for some reason. Any help would be appreciated.

So here is my function that selects the main event. Events have been previously fetched from the DB, with linked dates stored under the key "dates". They are passed to the function through the argument "$events".
Each date comes as an (int)unix date.

```
function getMainEvent(&$events){
    $today = time();
    $currentEvent = end($events); //selecting the last entered event (most likely to be the main event)
    $currentEventLast = max($currentEvent['dates']); //selecting the highest date linked to that event
    foreach($events as $k=>&$event){ //looping through events
        $date = min($event['dates']); //selecting the lowest date for the current event
        if($date>$today && $date<$currentEventLast){
        //if $date is higher than today (so it's not in the past), but lower than main event's date...
            $currentEvent = &$event; //make that event the main event
            $currentEventLast = max($currentEvent['dates']); //select the latest date of that event
        }
    }
    return $currentEvent;
}
```

Comment: Do you have to do this in PHP on the $events structure as is, or do you have the option to modify the SQL query to only give you the event you want?

Comment: No I could query the database, but since I am anyway getting all events to list them on the bottom, I'd rather just use that. It's not a performance thing (it's a very small website and two db calls would hardly be a problem), so I could go with a query if you have an idea, but I'd rather do that in PHP, if only just to learn.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm appears to have a number of problems.

- At the start of the function (before the loop), you set `$currentEventLast` as the highest date of the "last entered event". What happens if the "last entered event" has only dates that are in the past?
- At each pass through the loop, you set `$date` as the lowest date of the current event. What happens if that date is in the past?
- At each pass through the loop, if the `if` condition is true, you set `$currentEventLast` as the latest date of the current event. But shouldn't you set it as the date that you were just considering in the `if` condition?
- Not a crucial problem, but: What happens if the date of an event is today's date? The variable `$time` contains a timestamp. If it's one second past midnight then events happening today are judged "in the past" by your function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer. Indeed, you raise interesting questions. Let me try to answer and you tell me if I am thinking correctly or not:
 _What happens if "last" has only dates in the past?_ 

Well I guess if the rest of the funcion works, this should not be a problem. I could be selecting any random event from the list, this is just a starting point

; _At each pass...what happens if that date is in the past?_

& _shouldn't you set it as the date...if condition?_

Should I use max($dates) instead, you think?

Comment: As for the last point, yes, you are correct, but I can correct for this later, once the logic of my algorythm is sound